# variable constantly retaining value once set

Tags: php, xml, loops

I'm looping through a directory, trying to find XML files with errors.

```
$baddies = array();
foreach (glob("fonts/*.svg") as $filename) {

    libxml_use_internal_errors(true);

    $str = file_get_contents($filename);

    $sxe = simplexml_load_string($str);

    $errors = libxml_get_errors();

    $num_of_errors = 0;
    $num_of_errors = sizeof($errors);

    if ($num_of_errors > 0){

        array_unshift($baddies, $filename);

    }

 }
```

However it seems that once the errors are put into this object, they persist there through subsequent iterations of the loop, and files without errors still test positive. `$num_of_errors` remains high for good files. I have it being reset to zero, and have even tried `unset`ing it after each time through the loop. I suppose `libxml_get_errors` continues to retain a value once set. How can I reset it?

Comment: Have you tried ``libxml_clear_errors()``?

Comment: No, I didn't know it existed. That's worked. Brilliant, thank  you.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should use `libxml_clear_errors` function. As per document [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.libxml-get-errors.php) it says, the function keeps the errors stored in buffer.